# Windows create window API

Tags: c, windows, api, winapi, createwindow

I am new to Windows programming. On Windows OS, almost every application opens a window, and I want to know that if all these applications invoke the same API `CreateWindow()` to create their windows?

Or, another way to ask my question: Do Games, Music Players, Browsers, Instant Messaging, IDEs, etc create their window all by invoking API `CreateWindow()`? If not, what other APIs can be used to create a windows on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that and [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are the only APIs that can create a window (other related APIs such as `DialogBox` and `AllocConsole` also do this internally). No matter what graphics stack each application uses (WPF, DirectX etc) in the end it all boils down to a `CreateWindow`.

Comment: @rkosegi: Edited to mention that too. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Bloodmoon: Beware -- just because `CreateWindowEx` is *able* to create a window doesn't mean you should use it! It takes a **lot** of work to make the window actually *usable* -- you have to use `IsDialogMessage`, you have to change the font to the system default, you have to create the child windows properly (its own can  of worms), etc... it's something you probably don't want to do manually in C unless you have to!

Comment: @Mehrdad:thanks for your reminder, actually I just want to confirm that all the windows applications, especially games, will invoke the 'CreateWindow' API, and I will not call it by myself. In fact, I want to hook this API, therefore I do not care about the values of the arguments.

Comment: Why hook that call directly? There are higher lever hook methods that pick up on window creation. It's also a very good idea to fully understand the Win32 window and API structure before trying to hook into it.

Comment: @Deanna: do you know any high level APIs that can creat a window? And why cannot I hook 'CreateWindow' directly? What negative effects will this hook bring?

Comment: @bloodmoon Performance and stability. `CreateWindow()` is a VERY high traffic function, and there are hook methods explicitly for detecting window creation like CBT hooks. What exactly are you hooking for or trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Deanna: well, it's a long way until I arrive at here. For brevity, I want to hook the creation of a window -- especially the window that is created by games -- and mouse move&click on that window. Would yiu Please give me any guidance?

Comment: @Bloodmoon: As I said, use [CBT hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @deanna: can I set up two hooks in a a dll? I have another 'Message' hook in the dll I wrote.

Comment: @Deanna: can I set up two hooks in  a dll? I have another 'Message' hook via 'setwindowsHookEX' in the dll I wrote.